# TypeError: f.Goals is not a function

Tags: javascript, loops

I wrote this code for a school project about FIFA World Cups and I am getting the error TypeError: f.Goals is not a function(line 50) called from line 46. Please let me know how to fix this.

```js
 let fifa =[
          {
            Winner: 'Uruguay',
            Goals: 8,
            Goalscorer: 'Guillermo Stábile',
            Host: 'Uruguay',
            Year: 1930
          },
          {
            Winner: 'Italy',
            Goals: 5,
            Goalscorer: 'Oldřich Nejedlý',
            Host: 'Italy',
            Year: 1934
          },
          {
            Winner: 'Italy',
            Goals: 7,
            Goalscorer: 'Leônidas',
            Host: 'France',
            Year: 1938
          },
          {
            Winner: 'Uruguay',
            Goals: 8,
            Goalscorer: 'Ademir',
            Host: 'Brazil',
            Year: 1950
          },
          {
            Winner: 'West Germany',
            Goals: 11,
            Goalscorer: 'Sándor Kocsis',
            Host: 'Switzerland',
            Year: 1954
          },
          {
            Winner: 'Brazil',
            Goals: 13,
            Goalscorer: 'Just Fontaine',
            Host: 'Sweden',
            Year: 1958
          },
        ];
       
        let averageGoals = fifa.reduce(f => {
            let sum = function(a,b){
            return a+b;
            }
            return f.Goals(sum)/f.Goals.length;
        }
        );
```

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: f.Goals is really not a function, it is a number.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of the calling function is wrong:

1. Goals is a number, not a function
2. the reduce input are wrong
3. The average computation has to be computed on the total, not at every step of the reduce

here a possible solution:

```js
let fifa =[
      {
        Winner: 'Uruguay',
        Goals: 8,
        Goalscorer: 'Guillermo Stábile',
        Host: 'Uruguay',
        Year: 1930
      },
      {
        Winner: 'Italy',
        Goals: 5,
        Goalscorer: 'Oldřich Nejedlý',
        Host: 'Italy',
        Year: 1934
      },
      {
        Winner: 'Italy',
        Goals: 7,
        Goalscorer: 'Leônidas',
        Host: 'France',
        Year: 1938
      },
      {
        Winner: 'Uruguay',
        Goals: 8,
        Goalscorer: 'Ademir',
        Host: 'Brazil',
        Year: 1950
      },
      {
        Winner: 'West Germany',
        Goals: 11,
        Goalscorer: 'Sándor Kocsis',
        Host: 'Switzerland',
        Year: 1954
      },
      {
        Winner: 'Brazil',
        Goals: 13,
        Goalscorer: 'Just Fontaine',
        Host: 'Sweden',
        Year: 1958
      },
  ];
   
  let averageGoals = fifa.reduce((tot, f) => {
    return f.Goals + tot;
  }, 0) / fifa.length;
  
  
  console.log(averageGoals);
```